# How to pass emailAdapter arguments in docker compose file for parse-server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, parse-server

I have a docker compose file written to define parse-server. I want to enable email verification using the default mailgun adapter. 
Can someone help me how to pass the emailAdapter arguments in the compose file ?

```
my-parse-server: 
depends_on:
  - my-mongo 
container_name: "my-parser-server"
image : parseplatform/parse-server:latest
links:
  - my-mongo:mongo
command: '--appId testapp 
          --masterKey mykey 
          --databaseURI mongodb://mongo/test 
          --emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration 2*60*60 
          --preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail true
          --appName myApp
          --emailAdapter ????'
environment:
  VERBOSE: "1"
  PARSE_SERVER_VERIFY_USER_EMAILS: "true"
  PARSE_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL: "localhost"
ports:
  - 1337:1337
```

I tried passing this argument but this did not work

```
--emailAdapter {"module":"@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter","options":{"fromAddress":"mail@mailgun","domain":"sandbox@mailgun.com","apiKey":"mykey"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using docker, the best option is to use a configuration module.

The configuration module is passed as the last argument for the `command` parameter.

You can create a file, in your current folder, named `config.js` with:

```
module.exports = {
  appId: "testApp",
  databaseURI: "....",
  emailAdapter: {"module":"@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter","options": /* ... */}
}
```

Using this you will be able to do the following in your docker-compose.yml

```
my-parse-server: 
depends_on:
  - my-mongo 
container_name: "my-parser-server"
image : parseplatform/parse-server:latest
links:
  - my-mongo:mongo
command:  --masterKey mykey 
          --emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration 2*60*60 
          --preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail true
          --appName myApp
          /config/config.js
volume: ./:/config
environment:
  VERBOSE: "1"
  PARSE_SERVER_VERIFY_USER_EMAILS: "true"
  PARSE_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL: "localhost"
ports:
  - 1337:1337
```

This should now load your app properly.

You can add logs in the config.js in order to make sure it is properly loaded.

Comment: I was using  docker compose version 3 , and it worked with the following volumes: - ./config:/config

Comment: nice! Would be awesome to add to the docs, or the main repo in an example folder

Comment: Yes , I could not find this info in the docs .  I am working on a compose file using the official docker images to spin up a dev environment. I will share this example soon.

Comment: I did it not long ago, this was quite straightforward. I am always wary of the database though, going from local development to remote etc...